# VB6 call C# doesnt release

Tags: c#, vb6, idisposable

I have a VB6 code that call C# by using late binding, when the C# finish the VB6 doesn't release the C# reference, i tried implementing in the C# IDisposable
i tried setting the the reference to nothing and it didn't work

Is it possible that the VB6 code doesn't release the ref?
Is there any other way to release all reference to the C# code?
Is there any annotation i might use?

To give the whole story the VB6 is third party code, i cant add functionality/code call
to it.

Thanks
X

VB6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim obj As Object
    Set obj = CreateObject("test1.class1")
    obj.msg
    Set obj = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

C#

```
namespace test1
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Class1 : IDisposable
    {
        public void msg()
        {
            Console.Write("msg");
        }
        ~Class1()
        {
            Console.Write("~Class1");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
           Console.Write("Dispose");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the C# object is not getting released?  Don't forget that the .NET garbage collector is not deterministic.

Comment: Have you tried calling `Dispose()` explicitly in the VB6 code instead of just setting the reference to `Nothing` ?

Comment: the VB6 code is third party app, i cant add call to Dispose(), 
and i know it doesnt release the C# since when i tried build the C# again the DLL is locked by another process (VB6)...

Comment: Without `obj.Dispose()` you can't be sure the object is disposed

Comment: @eyalhayun If you want to rebuild or replace the DLL you must stop the VB6 app. That would also be true if the DLL were written in VB6. It's just the way it is.

Comment: @MarkJ I have stoped the VB6, but until i didn't close the IDE the DLL was not released.

Comment: Yep, if you are running the code from the IDE you must also close the IDE to unlock the DLL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply not the way memory management works in managed code.  The rules don't change just because you expose it as a [ComVisible] class.  Your vb6 code will release the CCW (COM callable wrapper).  But that just removes a reference to the C# object.  The object doesn't get destroyed and the finalizer won't run until the garbage collector runs.  Which in your posted snippet won't happen until the program terminates, you are not allocating enough managed objects to trigger a GC.

This is not a problem.